# Input field value opacity animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity

How can I animate the opacity of the value of an input field, say from 0.5 to 1.0 in 300 seconds and going back to 0.5 and looping this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function pulse() {
    $('#myElement')
        .animate({opacity:1.0}, 300)
        .animate({opacity:0.5}, 300, pulse);
}

pulse();
```

Assuming you meant 300ms ( http://jsfiddle.net/WtYSM/ )

Comment: i think you need to call that second animate() on the first one's callback and vice versa

Comment: Nope, the self-referential 'pulse' callback in the second animate restarts the loop. And this is safe from stack overflows.

Comment: Yes. The loop will be restarted only after completion of the second animate(). But will making 2 animate calls serially [elem.animate().animate()] make sure that the second of those calls (1 to 0.5) gets called only after the first one completes?

Comment: How can I apply this to an input field textarea instead o a div thus the text can use the animation ?

Comment: @VijayakrishnanK - yes, jQuery chains animations serially on elements unless you tell it to do otherwise.

Comment: @Hellnar - Just apply it to the text area instead of the div. It just works the same. Give the input tag an ID and reference that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the id of the element you want to animate is foo:

```
function toOpa05() {
    $('#foo').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 300, toOpa1);
}
function toOpa1() {
    $('#foo').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300, toOpa05);
}
toOpa05();
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/egVy4/

Comment: Thanks! How can I apply this to an input field text ? Say the text value fading from black to gray back and back?

Comment: You can do that by replacing foo in the above code with the id of your text input. But the above code alters the opacity of the whole input field, not just the text inside it. http://jsfiddle.net/egVy4/5/